# java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource[Report/quotation.jasper] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the

Tags: java, spring-boot, classpath, filenotfoundexception

The below code is working fine on local app:

```
String filePath = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:Reports/" + jaspername).getAbsolutePath();
```

But when I deployed it on UAT Server it through the below error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource[Report/quotation.jasper] cannot be resolved 
to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: 
jar:file:/C:/FolderName/application.jar!/BOOT_INF/Classes!/Reports/Quotation.jasper
```

Comment: Do you intend that to be packaged with the app or free floating in the file system?

Comment: It is packaged with the app and I have generated the jar file of the app.

Comment: Check that the file is present in the jar . If it is you should also be able to use ``getResourceAsStream``

Comment: Yes, the file is present in the jar. I have check the presence of the file though online jar file opener.

Comment: So did you try `getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Reports/quotation.jasper");`?

Comment: I have tried it but getClass().getResourceAsStream("/Reports/quotation.jasper"); return 'InputStream' and I need String here, ie. the path of the file.

Comment: *Why* do you need a `String`?

Comment: Because there is a library that takes file name with full class path, there I can't put resourceAsStream. That is why there is need of path name and the server is not taking this, but on local it works fine.

Comment: That library, unless it's been badly written, should include a call that takes a stream as an argument

Comment: Yes. But its a standared library for creating jasper report. Please give any idea for working this on server. Yet not find anything to solve this.

Comment: I can't really helps i don't know what the underlying Jasper call is.